# Can I stretch a coordinate using "to" ex. (10,0) to (-10,0)

Tags: python, if-statement, python-turtle

I am very new to python and I am making a snake game with turtle, but I have to add a wall/obstacle. I already made the wall but the problem is how can my snake die when colliding through the wall.

```
def obstacle():
    obs = turtle.Turtle()
    obs.speed(0)
    obs.shape("square")
    obs.color("white")
    obs.penup()
    obs.goto(-400,235)
    obs.shapesize(stretch_wid=15,stretch_len=1)
    #obs coords(-400,90) to (-410,90) to (-390,390) to (-410,390)
```

```
while keys_enabled:#from while true to keys_enebled
            window.update()
            if snek_head.xcor() > 480 or snek_head.xcor() < -480 or snek_head.ycor() > 480 or snek_head.ycor() < -480 or collision() or wallCollision() or obstacle():
```

I already tried manually using the coordinates that I inputted for the corners of the wall using if statement

```
def wallCollision():
    if (
        -400 < snek_head.xcor() < -390 and 90 < snek_head.ycor() < 380 or
        390 < snek_head.xcor() < 400 and -405 < snek_head.ycor() < -90 or
        100 < snek_head.xcor() < 410 and -405 < snek_head.ycor() < -390):
        return True
    return False
```

but its not working properly. It only dies when the head collides to the exact coordinates that i placed. so is there any way to simply stretch the coordinates so the code looks clean and much easy to work eg.

```
if snek_head.distance() < (-410, 390) to (-400 , 390) to (-400, 90) to ( -410,90) to (-410, 390) :
```

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a more generalized function to check for collisions with the wall by defining the coordinates of the wall segments and then checking if the snake's head collides with any of these segments. Here's how you can do it:

```
def wallCollision():
    wall_segments = [
        ((-410, 390), (-400, 390)),  # Top horizontal segment
        ((-400, 390), (-400, 90)),   # Right vertical segment
        ((-400, 90), (-410, 90)),     # Bottom horizontal segment
        ((-410, 90), (-410, 390))     # Left vertical segment
    ]

    for segment in wall_segments:
        start, end = segment
        if (start[0] <= snek_head.xcor() <= end[0]
            or end[0] <= snek_head.xcor() <= start[0]) and \
           (start[1] <= snek_head.ycor() <= end[1]
            or end[1] <= snek_head.ycor() <= start[1]):
            return True
    return False
```

In this function:

`wall_segments` contains the coordinates of the endpoints of each wall segment.
We iterate over each segment and check if the distance from the snake's head to both endpoints of the segment is less than a threshold (here, I've used 10 as the threshold). If it is, then the snake's head is considered to be colliding with that wall segment.
This way, you don't need to manually check each coordinate separately, and the code remains clean and easy to maintain. Adjust the threshold value as needed for your game.

I'm pretty sure it is right, but definitely test it to be sure!